# Putting JavaScript data inside an HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a pop up box that every time someone fires it (with delay), a counter displays that shows the number of clicks and the dates of the clicks!

How can I get the time and the clicks to be shown in a **cell** table something like this:

> ```
> Clicks         Time
>
>  1            thusday 4 2018
>  2            monday 3 2018
> ```

Here is my HTML code:

```js
function Msg1() {
  document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Hey <strong>Thanks!</strong>';
}

var counter1 = 1;
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var input = document.getElementById("popup-delay");
var showButton = document.getElementById("popup-show");
var closeButton = document.getElementById("popup-close");

showButton.addEventListener("click", function onShowClick() {

  // Get the user input and convert it into a number
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);

  // If the input is not a number
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    // Warn the user
    alert("NaN (Not A Number) !");
  }
  // Otherwise
  else {

    // Convert milliseconds to seconds
    var delay = value * 1000;

    // Turn off the click listener on the "Show" button
    showButton.removeEventListener("click", onShowClick);

    // Start the countdown to show the popup
    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = counter1;
    counter1 = counter1 + 1;
    document.getElementById("num4").innerHTML += "<span>" + Date() + "</span>";
    setTimeout(function() {

      // Show the popup
      popup.style.display = "block";

      // Turn on the click listener on the "Close" button
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", function onCloseClick() {

        // Turn off the click listener on the "Close" button
        closeButton.removeEventListener("click", onCloseClick);

        // Turn on the click listener on the "Show" button
        showButton.addEventListener("click", onShowClick);

        // Hide the popup
        popup.style.display = "none";
      });
    }, delay);
  }
});
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1em;
}

#thecounter {
  float: right;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#thetime {
  float: right;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#num4 span {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
Delay: <input type="text" id="popup-delay" />  <button type="button" id="popup-show">Show</button>
<div id="popup">
  <p>I am a popup :-)</p>
  <button type="button" id="popup-close">Close</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="thecounter">
    <p id="num2">clicks </p>
    <p id="num1">0 </p>
  </div>
  <div id="thetime">
    <p id="num3">time </p>
    <p id="num4"> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and your js code?

Comment: This is not a *Please give some code* website. Providing just HTML and CSS code is not right since what you are asking for needs JavaScript Code. Provide the js code so that we can *troubleshoot* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the elements by id before the dom rendered so it always get null value
just change the event listener of the button to  a function like below

```
 function onShowClick () {

var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var input = document.getElementById("popup-delay");
var showButton = document.getElementById("popup-show");
var closeButton = document.getElementById("popup-close");
  // get the user input and convert it into a number
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  // if the input is not a number
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    // warn the user
    alert("NaN (Not A Number) !");
  }
  // otherwise
  else {
    // convert milliseconds to seconds
    var delay = value * 1000;
    // turn off the click listener on the "Show" button
    showButton.removeEventListener("click", onShowClick);
    // start the countdown to show the popup
   //      document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML= counter1;
      counter1= counter1+1; 
      let currDate = Date();
 //   document.getElementById("num4").innerHTML += "<span>" + currDate + "</span>"; 
 // add new Row
      let table = document.getElementById("table");
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var tdCounter = document.createElement('td');
       tdCounter.appendChild(document.createTextNode(counter1))
      tr.appendChild(tdCounter)
      var tdTime = document.createElement('td');
      tdTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currDate))
      tr.appendChild(tdTime)

       table.appendChild(tr)

    setTimeout(function () {
      // show the popup
      popup.style.display = "block";
      // turn on the click listener on the "Close" button
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", function onCloseClick () {
        // turn off the click listener on the "Close" button
        closeButton.removeEventListener("click", onCloseClick);
        // turn on the click listener on the "Show" button
        showButton.addEventListener("click", onShowClick);
        // hide the popup
        popup.style.display = "none";



      });
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

and call it on onclick  in html for the button  like below

```
    <body>
Delay: <input type="text" id="popup-delay" />
<button type="button" onclick="onShowClick()" id="popup-show">Show</button>
<div id="popup">
  <p>I am a popup :-)</p>
  <button type="button" id="popup-close">Close</button>
</div>


<div id="container">
<table id="table">
</table>    

</div>
</body>
```

the out put like below

[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHxcr.png)
[Pop up Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONW2n.png)

Comment: @david did you change your html body like above and also java script function

Comment: yes, and nothing happens i try to put 2 second delay press the button and nothing . sir

Comment: check the answer update you will find screen shots with output and if you still have the issue update the question with your code now or send me link to it  and i will check it

Comment: i have seen the out put but it dosent come out in the editor ' the delay dosent work so as the buttons and there is no table to seen.

Comment: can you set here a editor that i can see the code in action? not a photo

Comment: check this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/SbToCbFwWVqC74qGiPvb?p=preview

Comment: But the table doesn’t have lines

Comment: add border to the table

Comment: thanks works great!  is it possible to:  lets say after 30 dates in the table list , to have abutton to  second page of the table list, and the table list continue.